# Understanding a hack attempt

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a simple mechanism that saves analytics into a mysql table for a key I'm getting in an http request. For example for the url

```
http://example.com?analyticsKey=button1
```

I'm adding to a key-value table: key=button1, value=value+1

I understand this is def quite a dirty solution, but as I'm escaping the input, I'm don't see any reason to be concerned. However, I did notice these inputs were attempted:
`../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd` or `../../../../../../../../../../proc/self/environ` etc..

Did the hacker assume this input was used as a file path to read from? Is this in anyway common?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal

Comment: Robots will try all sorts of things automatically without concern for if they will work or not. Most production sites are hit with a variety of "hacks" like this several times a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attacker (or) automated-scanner had attempted a `directory-traversal` attack on your domain.

These automated tools that does these sort of `dirty jobs` to check if such directory or file exists **`with the help of response code`** returned by your webserver.

If your webserver returned a valid **`200`** response code for these attempts, then the attacker may have gained access into your server by some other `means`.

Comment: Does this apply to only `.php` files, or are all Web-based pages vulnerable Shankar? I.e.: `.html`, `.shtml` etc.

Comment: Hi fred ! Yeah this applies to any poorly configured webserver.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I am returning a `200` response code (not really sure why/how not). Is there any way I can check if he succeeded? Any basic thumb rules to avoid "poorly configured webserver"?

Comment: Create a `.htaccess` file and restrict those directories.

Comment: restrict `etc/passwd` from `htacess`? how?